# Parallel.ForEach slows down towards end of the iteration

Tags: c#, performance, parallel.foreach

I have the following issue :

I am using a parallel.foreach iteration for a pretty CPU intensive workload (applying a method on a number of items) & it works fine for about the first 80% of the items - using all cpu cores very nice.

As the iteration seems to come near to the end (around 80% i would say) i see that the number of threads begins to go down core by core, & at the end the last around 5% of the items are proceesed only by two cores. So insted to use all cores untill the end, it slows down pretty hard toward the end of the iteration.

Please note the the workload can be per item very different. One can last 1-2 seconds, the other item can take 2-3 minutes to finish.

Any ideea, suggestion is very welcome.

Code used:

```
var source = myList.ToArray();
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, source.Lenght);
using (SqlConnection connection =new SqlConnection(cnStr))
{
   connection.Open();
   try
   (
      Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) =>
      {
         for(int i = range.Item1; i<range.Item2; i++)
         {
            CPUIntensiveMethod(source[i]);
         }
       });
   }
   catch(AggretateException ae)
   { //Exception cachting}
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? Are you trying to execute SQL statements "in parallel" over a *single* connection? Why do you think that "parallel execution" will help with SQL performance issues?

Comment: I would not use a single connection, multithreaded. Connections are pooled. You should create a connection for each thread.

Comment: Try applying a max degree of parallelism equal to the number of CPU cores: `Parallel.ForEach(..., new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount } ... )`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen note the SqlConnection. I suspect the OP is trying to fix a sql performance issue by brute forcing sql commands, which of course results in the opposite result, due to blocking

Comment: This looks like a case of [the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The OP has a SQL performance problem and assumes it can be fixed by executing commands in parallel. When that fails, the OP asks about `Parallel.ForEach` instead of the *actual* problem, which should be answered eg using SqlBulkCopy, TVPs, rewriting the inefficient SQL statement or batching multiple commands into one

Comment: In the CPUIntensiveMethod per each item i get a list of other items from a SQL server and process these.

Comment: @Horia then don't. Write *one* statement only, that accepts a list of IDs and uses an `IN ....` clause to return all the results,  or joins with a table valued parameter with the IDs. How many records are you trying to load? Where do the IDs come from? If they come from the database you could combine all queries into one

Comment: Also, did you ensure the table has the proper indexes? Without proper indexes a query has to process all existing data to find the matching records. By running more of them in parallel, you are making things a lot worse by forcing multiple full scans in parallel

Comment: i use 24 cores. I don't expect sql issues - the SQL Server is a separate server which works fine. For a run that last 3 hours, the first 2 hours are running fine and then, step by step the number of threads go down. I see also in task manager that the CPU goes slowly from 100% usage down as the number of threads go down. Per each item i can get between 2 and 5000 items to be processed.

Comment: @Horia you misunderstand. Each separate command requires some time to go to the server and come back. A single batched command though avoids excess round-trips. In any case, on an ETL scenario you are dealing with *streams* of data. That means that you want eg  a few workers in a pipeline processing data at the CPU's maximum. That's what SSIS does. That's also what the TPL dataflow does. `Parallel.ForEach` though just splits the input in X partitions that may *not* be balanced. If one of those partitions dries up, the relevant task will go idle.

Comment: You also lose the ability to split the ETL process in separate blocks that can run concurrently, the ability to specify different parallelism per step, caching between steps etc, all the stuff that SSIS gives you for free. TPL Dataflow provides equivalent functionality in code without the UI designers

Comment: For example, `Parallel` will create eg 8 partitions and start processing them in parallel. If one dries up, it won't repartition the data. On the other hand, an `ActionBlock<T>` with a DOP of 8 will process 8 input messages in parallel for as long as there are messages in its input buffer.

Comment: @Panagiotis: many thanks for your ideeas! I will try to see how ActionBlock works. Do you mean putting a normal foreach inside an ActionBlock<T>?

Comment: You don't have to. The TPL Dataflow library contains many blocks. Each block runs while there are input messages. An ActionBlock executes its delegate on each input message in sequence. A `TransformBlock` on the other hand returns a new message you can pass to the next block, just like a SSIS dataflow. Finally, a `TransformManyBlock` can return multiple values, eg the results of a query using input from a single message.

Comment: Do not use partitioning because the workload in each iteration is high.

Comment: The question looks alright because of the `CPUIntensiveMethod()`. But the presence of the SqlConnection is distracting and confusing. Yo do realize that that connection cannot be shared between threads, right? So remove it or explain its roll  a lot better.

Comment: I'm having the same issue even though my tasks are all almost the same complexity. I'm searching for strings in a shared very big string, which uses all 8 cores for 20 seconds and then gets slower and slower for the next 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is an unavoidable consequence of the fact the parallelism is *per computation*.  It is clear that the whole parallel batch cannot run any quicker than the time taken by the slowest single item in the work-set.

---

Imagine a batch of 100 items, 8 of which are slow (say 1000s to run) and the rest are quick (say 1s to run).  You kick them off in a random order across 8 threads.  Its clear that eventually each thread will be calculating one of your long running items, at this point you are seeing full utilisation.  Eventually the one(s) that hit their long-op(s) first will finish up their long op(s) and quickly finish up any remaining short ops.  At that time you ONLY have some of the long ops waiting to finish, so you will see the active utilisation drop off.. i.e. at some point there are only 3 ops left to finish, so only 3 cores are in use.

---

*Mitigation Tactics*

- Your long running items might be amenable to 'internal parallelism' allowing them to have a faster minimum limit runtime.
- Your long running items may be able to be identified and prioritised to start first (which will ensure you get full CPU utilisation for a long as possible)
- (see update below) **DONT use partitioning in cases where the body can be long running** as this simply increases the 'hit' of this effect. (ie get rid of your rangePartitioner entirely).  This will massively reduce the impact of this effect to your particular loop

either way your batch run-time is bound by the run-time of the slowest item in the batch.

---

*Update* I have also noticed you are using partitioning on your loop, which massively increases the scope of this effect, i.e. you are saying 'break this work-set down into N work-sets' and then parallelize the running of those N work-sets.  In the example above this could mean that you get (say) 3 of the long ops into the same work-set and so those are going to process on that same thread.  As such you should *NOT* be using partitioning if the inner body can be long running. For example the docs on partitioning here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853(v=vs.110).aspx are saying this is aimed at short bodies

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple threads that process the **same** number of items each and each item takes varying amount of time, then of course you will have some threads that finish earlier.

If you use collection whose size is not known, then the items will be taken one by one:

```
var source = myList.AsEnumerable();
```

Another approach can be a Producer-Consumer pattern
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371